# Whole system backup and recovery

Tags: linux, backup, restore

I am currently backing up my Raspberry Pi 3 to a local NAS using this command:

`sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | gzip > /mnt/MyCloud/"$(date +%FT%T)".gz`

This should run daily, using cron job.

- Is this enough for recovery, if the drive dies?
- Is there a better/faster way?
- If I want to recover the entire system, how would I go about it? The drive is compressed, so I can't just `dd if=my-backup.gz of=/dev/mmcblk0`, I think

Comment: Are  you shutting down the rPi, moving the sdcard to another system and then running this command or are you doing it on a live filesystem?

Comment: Live system. Why?

Comment: Because unless you mounted it RO (read only) you may be backup up parts of the disk which get written to during the backup. Which means that you do not have a guaranteed working backup. Either mount everything which you backup as RO or use filesystem based backups which can compensate for that. (e.g. rsync with /dev/ excluded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is more than enough for recovery (actually it isn't recommended to do this on live system, but if you don't use frequently changed files such as database for example then system can figure how to restore itself on recovery. If you don't have a databases then just use `sync;sync;sync` before you starting whole system backup to be make sure file's cache flashed to drive)
2. read below for IMHO a better solution
3. just use `gunzip -c /path/to/your.image.gz | dd of=/dev/sdX`

IMHO it is waste of space on the backup drive, you are cloning the same unchanged content multiple times. Use `tar` in incremental mode, it will backup only changes between previous ones.

Simple example of incremental backup with `tar`

```
#!/bin/sh

TAR='/bin/tar'
DATE='/bin/date'
SrcDir='/'
BkpDir='/mnt/MyCloud'
f=$($DATE '+%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S')
snar="${BkpDir}/snar.diff" # If you need full backup then remove 
                           # ${snar} file before doing backup

[ -f "${snar}" ] && level=1 || level=0

$TAR -czf "${BkpDir}/${f}_dump.level.${level}.tgz"   \
    --listed-incremental=${snar}    \
    --no-check-device               \
    --totals                        \
    --level=${level}                \
    --directory=${SrcDir}           \
    --exclude=tmp/*                 \
    --exclude=media/*               \
    --exclude=mnt/*                 \
    --exclude=proc/*                \
    --exclude=sys/*                 \
    --exclude=dev/*                 \
    --exclude=run/*                 \
    --exclude=var/tmp/*             \
    --exclude=var/run/*             \
    --exclude=var/lock/*            \
    --exclude=var/cache/locate/*    \
    --exclude=var/dcc/dccifd                \
    --exclude=var/lib/amavis/amavisd.sock   \
    --exclude=var/lib/php5/sess_*           \
    --exclude=var/spool/postfix/dev/*       \
    --exclude=var/spool/postfix/pid/*       \
    --exclude=var/spool/postfix/private/*   \
    --exclude=var/spool/postfix/public/*    \
    --exclude=backup                        \
    --exclude=${BkpDir}                     \
    .
    exit $?
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked into using tar, and it is a better solution. I got stuck running: `cd / && tar -cvf mnt/MyCloud/backup-1.tar.gz -g mnt/MyCloud/backup.snar dev/mmcblk0`

Making tar to run from /, as it does not like slashes, and do incremental. Unfortunately, it just creates a 1kb snar file and a 10kb backup.. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I edit my answer to add simple example. Do not use `v` option of `tar` if you going to use it in `cron`, it slow down backup process a LOT !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm being simple here, but after looking at the options for DD and crontab for scheduling backups etc, I decided on a different approach, partly because I'm more used to the Windows systems.

1. Shutdown the RPi.
2. Remove SD card.
3. Go to Windows PC (Linux would work but using DD I suppose).
4. Use Win32DiskImager to **READ** the
   contents to file.

I only do this every few months, however other than system updates, very little changes on the sdcard.
[Win32 Disk Imager download @ sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

This would provide a full system backup. As stated above, I saw little point of having multiple copies of my entire drive other than to take up space. My method gives the full backup, and my other files (dlna music and webserve folder for e.g) aren't stored on the sdcard anyway, they are on a USB drive. My way is simple like me but it works. Otherwise the tar incremental backup approach looks very good.