# pros and cons of incremental vs differential backup?

Tags: backup, diff, hardlink

[`Back In Time`](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) says it saves full copies of changed files. And it links unchanged files via hardlinks. So this is a incremental backup.

What are Pros and Cons of an incremental backup (like done with [`Back In Time`](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime)) vs a differential backup?

When should I choose one over the other?

Comment: I afraid questions like yours are violate policy on this site. Answers to such questions would be primarily opinion based. There too much different backup strategies that would satisfy one's needs but will be unappropriated for other. BackInTime basically is wrapper around `rsync` that can do incremental backup and saving space using hard links that is useful when you need access archive often, but long term archives would more effective if one would utilize incremental backup using `tar` with compression. Narrow your questions so it wouldn't be to broad.

Comment: So much info out there, probably impossible to condense in an answer: https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/incremental-differential-backups/ – https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/differential-backup-vs-incremental-backup.html – https://www.computerweekly.com/news/1347703/Incremental-vs-differential-backup-A-comparison – https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/difference-differential-incremental-backup/ – http://novabackup.novastor.com/blog/differential-incremental-backup/ etc.

Answer (score 1):

While your questions is out of policies on this site, I think it may be helpful for others, so I would try to clarify it a little.

Terms incremental and differential backups mostly are very misleading and hard to understand. There no exact answer to the question - which one method is better than other because of different backup technologies implemented by some particular software and also different needs for backups. Someone need to have full snapshot in time that includes all files at backup time but other need to save only files that was changed from last backup.

Also, different operation system has some filesystem's capabilities that doesn't exist on other systems so implementation of differential and incremental backup will be very differ.

Basically all **differential backups** saving only data that was changed since **last FULL backup**.  While backuping only new changes relatively to the full backup are small, over time it start growing more and more since there would be a big difference between original full backup and current stage.

In contrast to differential backup, - **incremental backups** also saving only changed data, but it only saving the data that has changed since **the last backup — be it a full or incremental backup.** Incremental backups aren't growing as crazy as differential ones that's why it isn't so critical to take often full backup over time. As far as full chain of backups that beginning from full backup up to the last incremental one kept unchanged then it isn't a problem to recover data to the stage in previous time without sacrificing space on a backup storage.

Advantage of differential backup is that you need only two backups, the full one and that differential one that you need to restore in previous time.
With incremental backups, one need to restore full chain of backups staring from full backup.

This is the primary difference between differential and incremental backup.

For example, take a look at `tar` that can do classic incremental backup. I posted no so long ago example of incremental backup [here](https://superuser.com/a/1166566/164837) that using `tar` utility. `tar` in that script creating dedicated, separate file where it keeps all changes(include deletion). This file keeps stage of last incremental backup. It easy to check if one would open intermediate incremental backup file and will found only changed/new files and directories that happened since last backup only. This solution works very well to keep backups that wouldn't be accessed often (thanks to compression). To restore completely such archives, one need to unpack first (level=0) full backup and sequentially restore all incremental (level=1) backup in order as it was saved. A little longer process of restoration to compare with differential, but backups will be kept as small as possible.

BackInTime that you referenced in your question is basically a wrapper around `rsync` utility.
Here is [example of incremental backup](https://superuser.com/a/1166566/164837) that utilize `rsync` capability to create incremental **snapshots**.
It is a little different to classic incremental backup because such solution creating a copy of the data as if it were frozen at a specific point in time, it includes all files and directories that were a subject of backup.

In comparison to `tar`, such solution create snapshots in time, so if you check any snopshot it will include the whole directories and files as it was at time of backup. While it looks like a full backup, in fact it isn't, because `rsync` don't copy/create files that already exist in previous backup, but instead `rsync` creates hard links to existing data that prevent wasting space on backup device. This way such snapshots will be incremental but it would looks like a full backup in the same time.
Such solution is very helpful if one need to access backuped data as soon as possible without spending time on unpacking and would see exact stage of snapshot in time that one needed.

I hope this information would help someone when one counting Pros and Cons regarding differential vs incremental backup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that a differential backup is a cumulative backup of the last _full_ backup. I thought the diff would always be taken from the _last_ backup taken. Is there such a method like always taking diff from the last backup? And what's the name for it?

Comment: The method that always taking difference from last backup is - incremental.

Answer (score 0):

I think „full-copy-backups“ have these advantages:

- only corrupt files on the filesystem are lost, all others can be restored
- deleted files on the backup-drive can more likely be restored (I hope this can be understood)
- restoring files is faster

More answers are welcome .

Comment: `rsync` which is the primary tool behind BackInTime doing FULL backup at first run and all subsequent calls saving changes, effectively creating shapshots in time. If some snapshot doesn't have some files (deleted), one can go back in folders and found deleted files in previous snapshots. If  your backup disk is healthy there won't  be cases like *"only corrupt files on the filesystem are lost"*, but if backup hdd is failing then there no trust to such backup at all.   *deleted files can more likely* - not more likely, they can be restored if backup saved such files for sure.